# Display screen/activity on Unlock event?

Tags: android

I essentially want to display a screen whenever the screen is unlocked regardless of the application already running.

Can someone just tell me how to display text as soon as the phone gets unlocked. I can take it from then on.

I have the following code up till now which I found on the net....

Suppose I want to display `abc.xml` as soon as the phone gets unlocked. How will i add it in the ScreenReceiver Class ?

Also I do not want to set any screen when the application runs.Do I need to run the code below as service ?

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

//Declare the necessary variables
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
     filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

     mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

   }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method: onDestroy()");

        if (mReceiver != null)
        {
             unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
             mReceiver = null;
        }          

    }

}
```

where the Screen Reciever class is as follows

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
      {    
            Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
            // onPause() will be called.
      }
      else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
      {
            Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
            //onResume() will be called.

            //  Better check for whether the screen was already locked
            //if locked, do not take any resuming action in onResume()

            //Suggest you, not to take any resuming action here.       
      }
      else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
      {
            Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_USER_PRESENT");
            //  Handle resuming events

      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one, you don't display `abc.xml`, you display an activity, dialog, or other UI component.  You can set up a broadcast receiver that listens for the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` intent.  Once the device boot completes, you can start a sticky service to listen for the actions you have above.  Presumably you'll want to display `abc.xml` in an activity, so you'll need to fire `startActivity` from one of the `if()` blocks above.