# How to Capture Image When Device is Locked

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-capture

I want to capture image automatically by using either front or rear camera from an android device when screen is locked and someone try to unlock it. I checked it is possible in Android and some application is available in Market. Please help.

Comment: Register for the screen on event via BroadcastReceiver and launch an activity that uses the Camera API to take a picture.

Comment: will you please elaborate this..

Comment: Hi, I managed to find the following application on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.midasensemble.hiddeneye see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Yes there are number of application for this but How it is working. how can i do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, you have two subproblems:

**1) Detect when device is unlocked**

As I understand it's reasonably straight forward.

All you need is to have BroadcaseReceiver subscribed to this action (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT).

You read more about this here:

- [Display screen/activity on Unlock event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968959/display-screen-activity-on-unlock-event)
- http://funwithdc.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/the-problem-with-androids-action_user_present-intent/
- [Why is my BroadcastReceiver receiving ACTION_USER_PRESENT twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273614/why-is-my-broadcastreceiver-receiving-action-user-present-twice)

**2) Take a picture from bakground**

I am not 100% sure whether it's possible or whether it works on all devices. As I know Camera requires to have some preview. However, as I understand it could be invisible preview.

Generally speaking, you want to take a picture either from broadcastreceiver or if you will have problem with that, just create additional service, trigger it from broadcast receiver and take a pictures from there.

Take a look at these questions (they show samples how to do invisible preview):

- [Taking picture from camera without preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386025/android-camera-without-preview/5384913#5384913)
- [How to use Camera to take picture in a background Service on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398897/how-to-use-camera-to-take-picture-in-a-background-service-on-android)

Combining these two things should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks Victor for your reply I am able to get the broadcast for user wrong input. also I am able to take the image from background but Image is black... I need to resolve this only Here is the more detail on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075726/capture-image-while-device-is-locked-with-password

Answer (score 0):

You can override the lockscreen to be your app, and then you can capture images like the rest of the app (google can help you with that).

Comment: Yes that was a solution but i Don't want to override the native lock screen. And it is possible to do that too.